# Standard equation of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm a bit confused. I read in many places that the standard equation of a line in $R^2$ is the following:

$w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 = d$

but I found a resource that mentions it as:

$w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + d = 0$

Shouldn't it be $w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 - d = 0$??

Comment: You can define $D = -d $

Comment: Nobody said that it was the same $d$. Or did they?

Comment: It does not matter since $d$ is a constant. Take your last equation and define $c=-d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two different $d$'s. The equations
$$w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 = d$$
and
$$w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + d' = 0$$
are equivalent when $d=-d'$.

Answer (score 0):

$d$ is a constant real number (positive or negative), so both equations equally represent a line in $R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

These are just arbitrary variables (or "names" for variables) - I think you would have been less confused had they written:

$$ax+by=d$$